# Get access to "Symbol(context)" properties of Node.js URL object

Tags: node.js, webstorm

There is an entry `Symbol(context)` for URL object, while debugging in WebStorm:

[image]

Is there a way to access these properties with URL object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finding symbol properties on objects**

The method `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` returns an array of symbols and lets you find symbol properties on a given object. Note that every object is initialized with no own symbol properties, so that this array will be empty unless you've set symbol properties on the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Electron, this might be caused by trying to expose the url module to the renderer. E.g. I had the following code in `preload.js`:

```js
const url = require('url');
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('nodeUrl', url);
```

Then in my renderer I tried to get the URL to a file I was trying to load with this code:

```js
const absoluteFilename = '/Users/myuser/Desktop/test.png';
const fileUrl = nodeUrl.pathToFileURL(absoluteFilename)
console.log(fileUrl); // {Symbol(context), Symbol(query)}
```

**This does not work** because Electron [can not bridge symbols](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge#parameter--error--return-type-support).

To solve this, I created a wrapper around `pathToFileURL` that returned a string and exposed that in `preload.js`:

```
const url = require('url');
const pathToFileURL = (filename) => url.pathToFileURL(filename).toString();
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('pathToFileURL', pathToFileURL);
```